How to calculate height of the center of the H2 molecule from surface via ASE?
I have XDATCAR file, i want to calculate graph of time vs height of the H2 molecule(center of the H2 molecule) from surface.
 bare_Pt_111_2*2_4                       
           1
     5.501291    0.000000    0.000000
     2.750645    4.764258    0.000000
     0.000000    0.000000   27.229464
   Pt   H 
  24   2
Direct configuration=     1
   0.16666667  0.16666667  0.99430037
   0.66666663  0.16666667  0.99430037
   0.16666666  0.66666669  0.99430037
   0.66666669  0.66666669  0.99430037
   0.83333331  0.33333334  0.07937458
   0.33333334  0.33333334  0.07937458
   0.83333337  0.83333331  0.07937458
   0.33333331  0.83333331  0.07937458
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.16390102
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.16390102
   0.00000000  0.49999997  0.16390102
   0.50000000  0.49999997  0.16390102
   0.16666667  0.16666667  0.24850018
   0.66666663  0.16666667  0.24850018
   0.16666666  0.66666669  0.24850018
   0.66666669  0.66666669  0.24850018
   0.83333331  0.33333334  0.33302660
   0.33333334  0.33333334  0.33302660
   0.83333337  0.83333331  0.33302660
   0.33333331  0.83333331  0.33302660
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.41810080
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.41810080
   0.00000000  0.49999997  0.41810080
   0.50000000  0.49999997  0.41810080
   0.51092067  0.49191322  0.53282254
   0.47561090  0.58716316  0.51029332
Direct configuration=     2
   0.16666667  0.16666667  0.99430037
   0.66666663  0.16666667  0.99430037
   0.16666666  0.66666669  0.99430037
   0.66666669  0.66666669  0.99430037
   0.83333331  0.33333334  0.07937458
   0.33333334  0.33333334  0.07937458
   0.83333337  0.83333331  0.07937458
   0.33333331  0.83333331  0.07937458
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.16390102
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.16390102
   0.00000000  0.49999997  0.16390102
   0.50000000  0.49999997  0.16390102
   0.16666667  0.16666667  0.24850018
   0.66666663  0.16666667  0.24850018
   0.16666666  0.66666669  0.24850018
   0.66666669  0.66666669  0.24850018
   0.83333331  0.33333334  0.33302660
   0.33333334  0.33333334  0.33302660
   0.83333337  0.83333331  0.33302660
   0.33333331  0.83333331  0.33302660
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.41810080
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.41810080
   0.00000000  0.49999997  0.41810080
   0.50000000  0.49999997  0.41810080
   0.51092111  0.49268582  0.53347959
   0.47506392  0.58852454  0.51073718
Direct configuration=     3
   0.16666667  0.16666667  0.99430037
   0.66666663  0.16666667  0.99430037
   0.16666666  0.66666669  0.99430037
   0.66666669  0.66666669  0.99430037
   0.83333331  0.33333334  0.07937458
   0.33333334  0.33333334  0.07937458
   0.83333337  0.83333331  0.07937458
   0.33333331  0.83333331  0.07937458
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.16390102
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.16390102
   0.00000000  0.49999997  0.16390102
   0.50000000  0.49999997  0.16390102
   0.16666667  0.16666667  0.24850018
   0.66666663  0.16666667  0.24850018
   0.16666666  0.66666669  0.24850018
   0.66666669  0.66666669  0.24850018
   0.83333331  0.33333334  0.33302660
   0.33333334  0.33333334  0.33302660
   0.83333337  0.83333331  0.33302660
   0.33333331  0.83333331  0.33302660
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.41810080
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.41810080
   0.00000000  0.49999997  0.41810080
   0.50000000  0.49999997  0.41810080
   0.51071250  0.49401136  0.53401679
   0.47472510  0.58932857  0.51129923
Direct configuration=     4
   0.16666667  0.16666667  0.99430037
   0.66666663  0.16666667  0.99430037
   0.16666666  0.66666669  0.99430037
   0.66666669  0.66666669  0.99430037
   0.83333331  0.33333334  0.07937458
   0.33333334  0.33333334  0.07937458
   0.83333337  0.83333331  0.07937458
   0.33333331  0.83333331  0.07937458
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.16390102
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.16390102
   0.00000000  0.49999997  0.16390102
   0.50000000  0.49999997  0.16390102
   0.16666667  0.16666667  0.24850018
   0.66666663  0.16666667  0.24850018
   0.16666666  0.66666669  0.24850018
   0.66666669  0.66666669  0.24850018
   0.83333331  0.33333334  0.33302660
   0.33333334  0.33333334  0.33302660
   0.83333337  0.83333331  0.33302660
   0.33333331  0.83333331  0.33302660
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.41810080
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.41810080
   0.00000000  0.49999997  0.41810080
   0.50000000  0.49999997  0.41810080
   0.51031920  0.49582033  0.53445016
   0.47457005  0.58964489  0.51196374
Direct configuration=     5
   0.16666667  0.16666667  0.99430037
   0.66666663  0.16666667  0.99430037
   0.16666666  0.66666669  0.99430037
   0.66666669  0.66666669  0.99430037
   0.83333331  0.33333334  0.07937458
   0.33333334  0.33333334  0.07937458
   0.83333337  0.83333331  0.07937458
   0.33333331  0.83333331  0.07937458
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.16390102
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.16390102
   0.00000000  0.49999997  0.16390102
   0.50000000  0.49999997  0.16390102
   0.16666667  0.16666667  0.24850018
   0.66666663  0.16666667  0.24850018
   0.16666666  0.66666669  0.24850018
   0.66666669  0.66666669  0.24850018
   0.83333331  0.33333334  0.33302660
   0.33333334  0.33333334  0.33302660
   0.83333337  0.83333331  0.33302660
   0.33333331  0.83333331  0.33302660
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.41810080
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.41810080
   0.00000000  0.49999997  0.41810080
   0.50000000  0.49999997  0.41810080
   0.50986803  0.49777561  0.53485985
   0.47447178  0.58981113  0.51265218
Direct configuration=     6
   0.16666667  0.16666667  0.99430037
   0.66666663  0.16666667  0.99430037
   0.16666666  0.66666669  0.99430037
   0.66666669  0.66666669  0.99430037
   0.83333331  0.33333334  0.07937458
   0.33333334  0.33333334  0.07937458
   0.83333337  0.83333331  0.07937458
   0.33333331  0.83333331  0.07937458
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.16390102
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.16390102
   0.00000000  0.49999997  0.16390102
   0.50000000  0.49999997  0.16390102
   0.16666667  0.16666667  0.24850018
   0.66666663  0.16666667  0.24850018
   0.16666666  0.66666669  0.24850018
   0.66666669  0.66666669  0.24850018
   0.83333331  0.33333334  0.33302660
   0.33333334  0.33333334  0.33302660
   0.83333337  0.83333331  0.33302660
   0.33333331  0.83333331  0.33302660
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.41810080
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.41810080
   0.00000000  0.49999997  0.41810080
   0.50000000  0.49999997  0.41810080
   0.50952478  0.49944479  0.53534966
   0.47426421  0.59026083  0.51326245
Direct configuration=     7
   0.16666667  0.16666667  0.99430037
   0.66666663  0.16666667  0.99430037
   0.16666666  0.66666669  0.99430037
   0.66666669  0.66666669  0.99430037
   0.83333331  0.33333334  0.07937458
   0.33333334  0.33333334  0.07937458
   0.83333337  0.83333331  0.07937458
   0.33333331  0.83333331  0.07937458
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.16390102
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.16390102
   0.00000000  0.49999997  0.16390102
   0.50000000  0.49999997  0.16390102
   0.16666667  0.16666667  0.24850018
   0.66666663  0.16666667  0.24850018
   0.16666666  0.66666669  0.24850018
   0.66666669  0.66666669  0.24850018
   0.83333331  0.33333334  0.33302660
   0.33333334  0.33333334  0.33302660
   0.83333337  0.83333331  0.33302660
   0.33333331  0.83333331  0.33302660
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.41810080
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.41810080
   0.00000000  0.49999997  0.41810080
   0.50000000  0.49999997  0.41810080
   0.50938629  0.50058152  0.53598017
   0.47385089  0.59123985  0.51373508
Direct configuration=     8
   0.16666667  0.16666667  0.99430037
   0.66666663  0.16666667  0.99430037
   0.16666666  0.66666669  0.99430037
   0.66666669  0.66666669  0.99430037
   0.83333331  0.33333334  0.07937458
   0.33333334  0.33333334  0.07937458
   0.83333337  0.83333331  0.07937458
   0.33333331  0.83333331  0.07937458
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.16390102
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.16390102
   0.00000000  0.49999997  0.16390102
   0.50000000  0.49999997  0.16390102
   0.16666667  0.16666667  0.24850018
   0.66666663  0.16666667  0.24850018
   0.16666666  0.66666669  0.24850018
   0.66666669  0.66666669  0.24850018
   0.83333331  0.33333334  0.33302660
   0.33333334  0.33333334  0.33302660
   0.83333337  0.83333331  0.33302660
   0.33333331  0.83333331  0.33302660
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.41810080
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.41810080
   0.00000000  0.49999997  0.41810080
   0.50000000  0.49999997  0.41810080
   0.50940391  0.50131512  0.53672059
   0.47328069  0.59261880  0.51409999
Direct configuration=     9
   0.16666667  0.16666667  0.99430037
   0.66666663  0.16666667  0.99430037
   0.16666666  0.66666669  0.99430037
   0.66666669  0.66666669  0.99430037
   0.83333331  0.33333334  0.07937458
   0.33333334  0.33333334  0.07937458
   0.83333337  0.83333331  0.07937458
   0.33333331  0.83333331  0.07937458
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.16390102
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.16390102
   0.00000000  0.49999997  0.16390102
   0.50000000  0.49999997  0.16390102
   0.16666667  0.16666667  0.24850018
   0.66666663  0.16666667  0.24850018
   0.16666666  0.66666669  0.24850018
   0.66666669  0.66666669  0.24850018
   0.83333331  0.33333334  0.33302660
   0.33333334  0.33333334  0.33302660
   0.83333337  0.83333331  0.33302660
   0.33333331  0.83333331  0.33302660
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.41810080
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.41810080
   0.00000000  0.49999997  0.41810080
   0.50000000  0.49999997  0.41810080
   0.50942080  0.50204571  0.53747260
   0.47271082  0.59399671  0.51445382
Direct configuration=    10
   0.16666667  0.16666667  0.99430037
   0.66666663  0.16666667  0.99430037
   0.16666666  0.66666669  0.99430037
   0.66666669  0.66666669  0.99430037
   0.83333331  0.33333334  0.07937458
   0.33333334  0.33333334  0.07937458
   0.83333337  0.83333331  0.07937458
   0.33333331  0.83333331  0.07937458
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.16390102
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.16390102
   0.00000000  0.49999997  0.16390102
   0.50000000  0.49999997  0.16390102
   0.16666667  0.16666667  0.24850018
   0.66666663  0.16666667  0.24850018
   0.16666666  0.66666669  0.24850018
   0.66666669  0.66666669  0.24850018
   0.83333331  0.33333334  0.33302660
   0.33333334  0.33333334  0.33302660
   0.83333337  0.83333331  0.33302660
   0.33333331  0.83333331  0.33302660
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.41810080
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.41810080
   0.00000000  0.49999997  0.41810080
   0.50000000  0.49999997  0.41810080
   0.50928149  0.50316283  0.53813866
   0.47229620  0.59498551  0.51489211


Please proofread this post!

@rubi-agrawal, could you post your output as a code block?

@Camps,   Yes, you can check.I have edited it.

Here is simple template which print Z-distance between centre of $\ce{H_2}$ molecule and nearest $\ce{Pt}$ atom.
Feel free to edit and plot.
from ase.io import read
import numpy as np
atoms=read("XDATCAR",":")

for atom in atoms:
    H2=atom[[at.index for at in atom if at.symbol=='H']]
    pt=atom[[at.index for at in atom if at.symbol!='H']]
    cen=np.average(H2.get_positions(),axis=0)
    pt_cord=pt.get_positions()
    distances = np.linalg.norm(pt_cord - cen, axis=1)
    nearest_index = np.argmin(distances)
    nearest_pt = pt_cord[nearest_index]  # nearest pt atom
    dis2H2=cen[2]-nearest_pt[2]  # z distance from top most pt atom
    print(dis2H2)



Thank you so much.
